# How do I get all executed commands programmatically in linux shell?

Tags: linux, shell, api, exec

Despite having the `history` file, how do I programmatically get every command being executed in shell?

Comment: If you activate audit subsystem you can get a lot of operations, executed on your linux.

Comment: @RomeoNinov I appreciate your feedback but I'd like to build a code myself to just get the executed commands with every other arguments provided to it.

Comment: Maybe this kernel api can help you: https://archive.kernel.org/oldlinux/htmldocs/kernel-api/audit.html

Comment: What research have you done and what have you tried? This is not a code writing service. Show us what you have tried, describe how it fails.